# How to hidepid on Arch Linux manually?

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, mount, security, proc

I have reinstalled Arch Linux to find that the package which used to be available called hidepid no longer exists, so I have to do [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Security#hidepid) manually, but as I am still relatively new to Arch, I am not sure how to do the following:

> The kernel has the ability to hide other users' processes from
>   unprivileged users by mounting the proc filesystem with
>   hidepid=1,gid=26 or hidepid=2,gid=26. The 26 gid is the proc group
>   provided by the filesystem package and acts as a whitelist. If a user
>   or service needs access to /proc/PID directories beyond their own, add
>   it to the group.

So how do I mount the proc filesystem with either or these parameters given and make this permanent?